# how can I tell if an Activity is reached through PendingIntent

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

Is there a way to tell if I reached some Activity through regular flow of the app or whether I reached this (deep) Activity from a `Notification` via `PendingIntent`?

I need to perform some operations when the application starts and if I got to this Activity via notification I need to make sure these operations are made.

Comment: I did it by sending a bundle with unique values like 1 for message 2 for about page, etc in the intent parameter of the pending intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an extra on your PendingIntent and than when the activity starts check for it using getIntent() ("Return the intent that started this activity."). Doing so you can getExtras() and check how the activity was started.